# Whether it is possible to have more than one controller / view for a Model in .Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Whether it is possible to have more than one controller / view for a same Model in .Net MVC?

i.e Having one Same Model (or) Table Schema for two different controller. We might have two different view as well.

Comment: Yes its possible. What problem are you having?

Comment: Yes. It is possible.You can create many controllers/views use the same underlying data layer(Model)

Comment: Depending on your requirements, having multiple controllers and views with single model class is possible. Note that you may create different viewmodels with same data model.

Comment: can confirm. as stated in above comments, it is posible.

Comment: Model is one kind of class so you can use it more than single time.

Comment: Thank you all. Yes, I am able to have different controller, view.  I am maintaining same model, view model.  There is no changes on it ..